# getting value of children

Tags: c#, json.net

My simple json data as below

```
   string _JsonData = @" {
       "tm":{
          "1":{
             "pl":{
                "11":{
                   "foo":"2"
                },
                "902":{
                   "foo":"70"
                }
             }
          }
       }";
```

I can get value of **pl** children's foo values (such as **2** and **70**) as below code

```
JObject _JObject = JObject.Parse(_JsonData);

foreach (JToken _JTokenCurrent in _JObject["tm"]["1"]["pl"].Children())
{
    MessageBox.Show(_JTokenCurrent["foo"].ToString());
}
```

So how can i get value of **pl** children's property values (such as **11** and **902**)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not call `_JTokenCurrent.Children()`?

Comment: `json` seems like missing one bracket. And you have posted same question twice.

Comment: If it wouldn't have been a programming question, The answer of your title would be Priceless :)

Comment: @HassanNisar yes i have asked before but deleted that. It was my fault.

Comment: @Pankaj sorry my english is not soo good.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have tried but it didn't work.

Comment: You should show us what you've tried, and what went wrong. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1):

OK I have solved as below;

```
JObject _JObject = JObject.Parse(_JsonData);

foreach (JToken _JTokenCurrent in _JObject["tm"]["1"]["pl"].Children())
{
    // get values such as 11 and 902
    JProperty _JTokenCurrentName = (JProperty)_JTokenCurrent;
    MessageBox.Show(_JTokenCurrentName.Name);

    /// get values such as 2 and 70
    MessageBox.Show(_JTokenCurrent["foo"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: what is `_JBoxScoreValue`?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested!

```
JObject _JObject = JObject.Parse(_JsonData);

foreach (JToken _JTokenCurrent in _JObject["tm"]["1"]["pl"].Children())
{
    // Should be your 11 and 902
    MessageBox.Show(_JTokenCurrent.Children().ToString());

    // Should be your 2 nad 70
    MessageBox.Show(_JTokenCurrent["foo"].ToString());
}
```